# convex fuction fullfills inequality with gradient

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider a convex function $f$ which is differentiable on closed convex set $Y$. Then it holds
$x$ is minimizer of f if $<\nabla f(x), x-y> \leq 0, \forall y \in Y$.

Proof:

Assume $<\nabla f(x), x-y> > 0$ and consider  $h(t)=f(x + t(y-x)) \Rightarrow h'(t) <0$

Why is this a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

If $h'(0) < 0$ then you can find a $t > 0$ such that $h(t) < h(0)$, which translates to

$$
f(x + t(y - x)) < f(x)
$$

Therefore $x$ can't be the minimizer, which contradicts your assumption.